# Type does not get fully applied

Tags: haskell

I have following code snippet from haskell book:

```
embedded' :: MaybeT (ExceptT String (ReaderT () IO)) Int
embedded' = MaybeT (ExceptT (ReaderT (const (return (Right (Just 1))))))
```

The type signature of `ExceptT` is as follow:

```
newtype ExceptT e m a =
  ExceptT { runExceptT :: m (Either e a)) }
```

Compare the type signature of the `embedded'` function with `ExceptT` type constructor:

```
        ExceptT   e             m                 a
                  |             |                 |
MaybeT (ExceptT String   (ReaderT () IO) (**missing here**)  ) Int
```

How can I just leave `ExceptT` as higher kinded?

I tried also:

```
fullType :: ExceptT String []
fullType = undefined
```

the compiler complains:

```
* Expecting one more argument to `ExceptT String []'
  Expected a type, but `ExceptT String []' has kind `* -> *'
* In the type signature:
    fullType :: ExceptT String []
```

Failed, modules loaded: none.

Comment: I didn't quite get what's missing. The `a` is `Int` in your case.

Comment: The `MaybeT` obtains a type of kind `* -> *`, and an `a`, `Int` and applies `a` to `* -> *`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably got confused by outmost `MaybeT`. This type is parametrised by 2 arguments of kinds `m :: * -> *` and `a :: *`, respectively. So, that `ExceptT String (ReaderT () IO)` is indeed missing an `a` because it is an `MaybeT` first argument and should be of kind `* -> *`. Had we apply `Int` to `ExceptT`, it would turn into `*` and then it can't be passed to `MaybeT`.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am not with my Haskell environment, so this might be utter nonsense.

Put in an explicit type variable for the missing spot on `ExceptT`:

```
embedded' :: MaybeT (ExceptT String (ReaderT () IO) a) Int
embedded' = MaybeT (ExceptT (ReaderT (const (return (Right (Just 1))))))
```

Hopefully the compiler can figure out what `a` should be!

What you're running into, which shows more obviously in your `fullType` example, is that it's not possible to give something a type of kind `* -> *`. Functions, values and so forth all need to have types of kind `*`.

Currying a type constructor gives you a `* -> *`, so you have to provide *something* for all the parameters.

Putting a type parameter in the signature for `embedded'` makes it kind `*`, but polymorphic over `a`.